# BadSqlGrammarException: [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME FROM BATCH_JOB_INSTANCEDuring while migrating to springbatch 5.0

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

During Spring Batch migration from 4.x to 5.0.3, I am facing issue related to initializing spring Batch table: BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE.

I have mostly followed Spring Batch 5.0 migration Guide:
My BatchConfiguration class:

```java
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Job reportGenerationJob(JobRepository jobRepository,Step step5,Step step6) throws Exception{
        log.info(">>>>>Inside Job reportGenerationJob");
        return new JobBuilder("reportGenerationJob",jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step5).on("*").to(step6)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    /*
     * Step to read  all records from DB,process  original Transactions from FUF and add them to a list
     */
    @Bean
    public Step step5(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws ParseException {
        log.info(">>>>>Inside Step 5");
        return new StepBuilder("step5", jobRepository)
                .<TSRequest, OriginalTransaction> chunk(20,transactionManager)
                .reader(transactionReader())
                .processor(transactionCsvProcessor())
                .writer(new SavingOriginalTransactionListWriter<>(originalTransactions))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step6(JobRepository jobRepository, Tasklet creatingSingleOutputPtmTransactions, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        log.info(">>>>>Inside Step 6");
        return new StepBuilder("step6", jobRepository)
                .tasklet(creatingSingleOutputPtmTransactions(),transactionManager)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use Spring Boot? Have you initialized the database with Spring Batch tables before running the job?